# Can Strapi be launched into AWS lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, strapi

i want a good cms/backend application to create/manage API on AWS.
strapi fits well for my requirement.
but i dont want to use EC2, lightsail, beanstalk etc

**i want to use strapi on aws lambda**
is it possible to deploy strapi on aws lambda?

Answer (score 3):

Since strapi is a nodejs project, you can use this project to deploy to aws lambda [Apex up](https://github.com/apex/up).

You can still deploy a monolith to aws lambda, but it is not suggested.

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion about it in https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1908

It states the [issue](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1908#issue-357507948) with runnig stapi on lambda is

> Currently there is a long bootup process which makes hosting strapi in an environment like aws lambda impractical since it has to boot the app for each request.

The [latest comment](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1908#issuecomment-625092946) from the team says

> We will not work on it for now. We will communicate if something changes on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I love strapi is an awesome tool. In my opinion if laravel can be installed in lambda, strapi can run. https://medium.com/artisanhost/hosting-a-laravel-application-on-aws-lamdba-90b7133c8578

The strapi core is koa. https://github.com/matthewmueller/lambda-serve
In my opinion you can run strapi in AWS Lambda.

Comment: wish, somebody could create a "launch on aws" deployment script

Answer (score -9):

It's not possible because Strapi has a monolithic architecture.

So it's doesn't match with an AWS Lambda usage.

Comment: Just because _something_ is monolithic doesn't mean it can't run _well_ in AWS Lambda. It's certainly possible to run a monolithic app in AWS Lambda, as long as constraints are met, e.g. size not bigger than 50 MB.

Comment: It's answers like this that make me truly regret not being more involved on Stack Overflow so I get enough reputation points to be able to use the downvote feature... 

Comment: @IonutBotizan - gotchu fam. Quite agree. Hendy - well said.